# How can I change SOAP element names to reserved words in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, soap, element, reserved-words

I use this line to register a class with the Delphi registry for Soap elements:

```
RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(ToHeader, ADD_URI);
```

In the Soap request message, I see this:

```
 <NS1:ToHeader> ... </NS1:ToHeader>
```

Is it possible to change the class registration so that it renders the element with a different name, like:

```
 <NS1:To> ... </NS1:To>
```

or is the only way to tweak the request stream?

To is a reserved word in Delphi, I can not rename the class to the element name 'To'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like that's what the third parameter is for. Try this:

```
RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(ToHeader, ADD_URI, 'To');
```

As of Delphi 8, you *can* use reserved words for identifiers. Use `&` as an escape character, or use a fully qualified name:

```
type
  &To = class;

RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(UnitName.To, Add_URI);
```

Comment: The & does help. I am not sure about the third parameter meaning, but have tried it already without visible effect. Many thanks for your input!